# how to display array values automatically using textview in android

Tags: android

I want to know that I want to display string one after another but in a particular time interval.

Everything is fine.in my code

I want to know that when second string print override the first one and third override the second and so on..using text view in android once i click the button all values comes automatically one after another

at regular time interval

How can I do this?

This is my code :

public class GameScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
Button start;

EditText type;

TextView Display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Game Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    init();
}

private void init() {

    Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstart);

    start.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bstart:

        String arr[] = { "mahtab", "hussain", "yasir", "azmi", "saif" };


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            Display.setText(arr[i]);


            try {

                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: use a timer or a handler to display the text.

Comment: how i use handler to display the text please provide me some hints...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Button start;

EditText type;

TextView Display;

private String displayText = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Game Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    init();
}

private void init() {

    Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstart);

    start.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bstart:

        String arr[] = { "mahtab", "hussain", "yasir", "azmi", "saif" };


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            displayText = displayText + arr[i];    
            Display.setText(displayText);


            try {

                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: sleep blocks the ui thread and blocking ui thread is not good

Comment: it prints all the values at one time i want when any one click on the button values automatically come one after another

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to sleep in main thread. You can use handle to sleep and post message to main thread, and update textview in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

use countdown timer:

//30000 -FOR How Long
//1000- interval after which the text will change

```
int i=0;
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {       
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
   mTextField.setText("" + array[i]);
    i++;        
}       

public void onFinish() {         
   mTextField.setText("done!");    
}   
}.start();
```